# Dates not equal to numbers

Tags: date, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018

I don't want this to be true

```
<cfset somedata = "12:00 AM">

<cfif "12:00 AM" EQ 0>
    Wow
</cfif>
```

Most of the time `somedata` has numbers. But it can have time. If it has `12:00 AM`, I don't want this if statement to return as true.

Comment: Did you try javacast(“string”, “12:00 AM”)?  I use cast a lot to ensure that CF isn’t converting the value into something that I don’t really want. You may be able to use isvalid(“integer”) before casting to ensure that you aren’t converting number-like strings to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like below ( Add condition `isNumeric(somedata)`), It will check `somedata EQ 0` condition only when the somedata is numeric.

```
<cfset somedata = "12:00 AM">

<cfif isNumeric(somedata) AND somedata EQ 0>
    Wow
</cfif>
```

For your scenario ( somedata = "12:00 AM" ) somedata is not numeric, so that time ( `isNumeric(somedata)` ) condition will failed. It will not go under if condition.